Other content get covered by background gradient
I'm trying to have a div with a moving background (you can find what I wrote so far here).
The main issue is that the moving background is covering up the other content on the page.
<!-- App.vue -->
<v-app>
  <v-main>
    <MainContent /> // contains the moving background
    <div style="height: 80px" class="bg-primary w-100"></div> // footer that should be always visible
  </v-main>
</v-app>

This is what MainContent.vue looks like
<template>
  <div class="background-gradient"></div>
  <div class="h-screen">
    <v-container class="fill-height position-relative">
      <div style="height: 500px" class="bg-black w-100"></div>
    </v-container>
  </div>
<template>

<style>
.background-gradient {
  background-image: linear-gradient(136deg, #e5ccab 0%, #e5ccab 1.26%, #e0cbad 19.87%, #d4c8b5 39.24%, #bfc3c2 58.96%, #a2bdd5 78.81%, #8ab8e5 92.48%, #8ab8e5 93.59%);
  position: fixed;
  width: 162vw;
  height: 162vh;
  /* z-index: -1; */
  animation: moveBackground 6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes moveBackground {
  0% {
    transform: translate(0, 0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: translate(-38%, -38%);
  }
}
</style>

This is the result

What am I doing wrong?

I left the commented out z-index in your demo but if I uncomment it, everything is shown. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/yLmjNod

Frankly though, using a div as the background is probably unnecessary. You could put the gradient on the body and adjust sizing and position with background-size and background-position... all CSS, no HTML

@Paulie_D I think it's because your code it's not quite like mine. I'm using Vue and Vuetify, maybe there's something there that changes the behaviour. You can find a link to the code in my question

@Paulie_D I can't because that bg has to be applied to the div only. The body bg must stay white

Then you need to reproduce the issue here with all the relevant CSS. As you say, there must be something else, you have to show us what else is happening. Even in your linked demo, uncommenting the z-index shows the blue footer.

@Paulie_D i edited again my question. That is all the code

This is the cleanest solution I came up with
<template>
  <div class="h-screen position-relative overflow-hidden">
    <div class="underlay-gradient position-absolute"></div>
    <v-container class="fill-height position-relative">
      <v-card width="100%" height="500px"></v-card>
    </v-container>
  </div>
  <div>
    <!-- Long text here -->
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
  .underlay-gradient {
    width: 162vw;
    height: 162vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
      136deg,
      #e5ccab 0%,
      #e5ccab 1.26%,
      #e0cbad 19.87%,
      #d4c8b5 39.24%,
      #bfc3c2 58.96%,
      #a2bdd5 78.81%,
      #8ab8e5 92.48%,
      #8ab8e5 93.59%
    );
    animation: moveBackground 6s ease-in-out infinite alternate;
  }

  @keyframes moveBackground {
    0% {
      transform: translate(0, 0);
    }
    100% {
      transform: translate(-38%, -38%);
    }
  }
</style>

Demo here

Set the z-index of the footer element so the browser understands how elements should overlap each other. Elements with a higher z-index will overlap elements with lower z-index. You probably don't want to set the background z-index to -1 because even non z-index elements will cover up the background (elements have default value of 0), such as v-container.  In fact, you don't need to set z-index on background-gradient at all. Just having the footer with z-index > 0 is all you really need.
App.vue
<div id="footer" style="height: 80px" class="bg-primary w-100"></div>

#footer {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
}

demo

It kinda works. I updated the sandbox link. I added a "Lorem ipsum" string which shouldn't have the gradient bg. The gradient bg should be scoped to the component only, but I don't understand how to achieve it

elements have transparent background by default, not white.  add background: white to the lorem ipsum div.

I understand, but does it mean the gradient bg is going to always occupy the whole screen? Shouldn't it stop somewhere and, after that, the bg goes back to the default?

the bg gradient has 162vh height, so yes it's going to occupy more than the whole screen by design in order to achieve the changing background illusion you're going for.

So might it be that this way of doing is not clean?
